# How to handle the GET method so that I can update the requested object before returning it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I'm working with an API implemented with Spring Data Rest and I would need to handle the GET method like I can do with the `@RepositoryEventHandler`, which allows me to handle before/after save, create, delete...

The case is that I need to update the object to be returned gathering information from other APIs before returning it as the GET response.

Is there any way to handle the GET in spring data rest?

Comment: Look into servlet filters

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use [@RepositoryRestController](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers) for this. It lets you get stuff from the @Repository and then add new things to the response object. Pretty similar to @RestController, but keeps Spring Data REST’s settings, message converters, exception handling, and more.

Answer (score 1):

you could add Interceptor implementing [HandleInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) and add it to mapped inteceptor bean.

```
@Bean
public MappedInterceptor myMappedInterceptor() {
    return new MappedInterceptor(new String[]{"/**"}, new MyInterceptor());
}
```